# How to make my logistic regression run faster?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, logistic-regression

My logistic regression code takes half an hour for 1000 iteration for 1000 images. How to make it faster.
After 6000 iteration I got a accuracy of aproximately 75%. But it took 3+ hours. The code is already vectorised but still it is slow

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import pickle
import sys
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
p1=open("p1.pickle","rb")
p2=open("p2.pickle","rb")
al=0.4
iteration=6000
def prep_data():
    a=cv2.imread(r"D:\New folder\New folder\cd\001cat.jpg")
    a=cv2.resize(a,(200,200))
    a=np.reshape(a,[120000,1])
    Y=np.ones((1))
    for im in os.listdir(r"D:\New folder\New folder\cd"):
        b=cv2.imread("D:\\New folder\\New folder\\cd\\" + im)
        if im[3]=='c':
            Y=np.hstack((Y,[1]))
        else:
            Y=np.hstack((Y,[0]))
        b=cv2.resize(b,(200,200))
        b=np.reshape(b,[120000,1])
        a=np.hstack((a,b))
    Y=Y.reshape(1,Y.shape[0])
    return(a,Y.shape[0],Y)
def sigmoid(x):
    return(1/(1+np.exp(-x)))
##X,ccount,Y=prep_data()
##pickle.dump([X,ccount,Y],p1)
X,ccount,Y=pickle.load(p1)
W=np.zeros(120000).reshape(120000,1)
b=0
def learn():
    global W,X,b
    for x in range(iteration):
        print("iteration "+str(x))
        Z=np.dot(W.T,X)+b
        A=sigmoid(Z)
        dZ=A-Y
        dW=(1/(ccount))*np.dot(X,dZ.T)
        dB=(1/(ccount))*np.sum(dZ)
        W=W-al*dW
        b=b-al*dB
    return(W,b)
W,b=learn()
##W,b=pickle.load(p2)
##pickle.dump([W,b],p2)
I=cv2.imread("D:\\New folder\\test1\\10.jpg")
I=cv2.resize(I,(200,200))
I=np.reshape(I,[120000,1])
print(sigmoid(np.dot(W.T,I)+b))
p1.close()
p2.close()
```

Comment: why don't use scikit-learn ?

Comment: I am new to machine learning so wanted to code a logistic regression from scratch so there isn't any point in using scikit learn I guess. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Scikit-learn logistic regression implementation has more efficient implementation than yours so it should be more faster than your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can optimize this code to become much faster than this, it is taking that long probably because of the size of the arrays, you can try to use libraries that already have a logistic regression (scikit-learn), it will probably save you a lot of time.

Comment: I am new to machine learning so wanted to code a logistic regression from scratch so there isn't any point in using scikit learn I guess. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yep, if your purpose is to learn maybe try creating it from scratch might be a good idea, but why don't you try your model in a toy dataset such as iris? It will surely run very fast and you won't have to be worrying about minor things like this

Comment: It is really rewarding for a beginer when a real dataset is used. Like it feels nice to know that your simple code can recogonise images

Comment: I understand, but ML code that does that usually uses an immense amount of processing power to run faster, you can use cloud computing if you want more processing power even though I think it isn't necessary for your case.